# Verifying if a set is connected/path connected.

Tags: general-topology

So I wanted to verify if these sets were connected/path connected because I don't really fully understand the definition although the idea seems a bit intuitive.

$$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \  |y| = \frac{1}{x}, x > 0\}$$

A set is disconnected if it can be written as a union of two non-empty sets. So this set should be disconnected because it can be written as a union of two non-empty sets. But since this is disconnected, this can't be path connected.

$$\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(x, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$$
where $x$ is irrational.

The way I see this set, this set is the real plane without irrationals on the x-axis. So I'm guessing that the complement is the irrationals? This set is disconnected but I'm not sure if that means the given set is disconnected... Any hints?

Comment: Any set with more than one point is the union of two non-empty sets.  That's **not** the definition of disconnected.  It might help if you stated the definition correctly.

Comment: Thanks. So these set have to be open as well correct? For the second set, how would I figure out if it's connected or disconnected based of the definition? It looks disconnected to me, but I can't figure out if it is.

Comment: You need to state the whole definition, not just a part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U = \{(x,y) | y > {1 \over 2 x}, x > 0 \}$ and let
$V = \{(x,y) | -y > {1 \over 2 x}, x > 0 \}$. Then $U,V$ are **open**, disjoint and
the first set above is contained in their union. If it is not connected it cannot be path connected.

For the second, take any point $(x,y)$ in the set. If $y\neq 0$ then draw a straight line to $(0,0)$. This line lies entirely in the set.
If $y = 0$ then draw a line from $(x,0)$ to $(1,1)$ (which also lies entirely in the set) and then to $(0,0)$ (same stuff repeated).

It follows that there is a path from any point to $(0,0)$ and hence there is 
a path joining any two points. Since it is path connected, it is connected.

Comment: This is for the first set right? Just making sure, you mean to write $\frac{1}{x}$ because you wrote $\frac{1}{2x}$. Also, I'm more... troubled by the second set, how would I figure if that's connected or disconnected? *edited* just saw your comment for the second set, that makes sense!

Comment: The two is there so that the set is open and contains the first set. I added an answer for the second. It helps to draw a diagram.

Comment: Ah thank you! That really helps since I was a bit confused, but this helps.